# I am trying to make a invite command, that dms the user, within a cog(discord.py)

Tags: python, discord.py

I am trying to make a invite command that when run, will DM the user a invite link to the server. This is the code:

```py
@commands.command(brief='A one time server invite',pass_context=True)
async def serverinvite(self, ctx):
    invitelink = await ctx.channel.create_invite(max_age = 90, max_uses=1, unique=True)
    await ctx.send(invitelink)
```

But I am having 2 issues. 1) When the command is in my cog, the cog will not load. 2)I cant figure out how to make it DM the invite link
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**First of all**, here are the *official docs* which can answer your query *pretty well*.

- [Constructing a cog](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/cogs.html?highlight=cogs)
- [Loading a cog using extensions](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/extensions.html?highlight=cogs)
- [Creating an instant invite](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=create_invite#discord.abc.GuildChannel.create_invite)
- [Sending a DM](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#how-do-i-send-a-dm)

now that you are trying to create an instant invite, your bot will require permissions to create an instant invite, if the bot is lacking permissions, this is **not** gonna work. Another way is to create a permanent invite link, and send it to the user on use of command (it will also help to stop flooding the invites section of server).

```
@commands.command(brief='A one time server invite',pass_context=True) 
async def serverinvite(self, ctx):
    invitelink = await ctx.channel.create_invite(max_age = 90, max_uses=1, unique=True)
    await ctx.author.send(invitelink)
```

the reasons that are stopping the bot on creating an invite can be...

- lack of permissions to create an invite
- the cog is not loaded using extensions